# Can't upgrade Android Studio Kotlin plugin to latest (1.4.21)

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.1

For some reason I have no option to upgrade my Kotlin plugin to the latest version.

Android Studio shows that the latest (1.4.21) is available:

[image]

But my installed version is still 1.3.72 and there's no option to upgrade it:

[image]

And suggestions? Is there another way to upgrade?

**I'm running Android Studio 4.1.1 stable build on macOS Catalina.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you wait long enough, the plug-in updater will finally notice it and offer to upgrade.

Comment: Wait for how long? i am having the same  issue